# Role-based access control security

Tags: access-control

How secure is role-based access control (RBAC). What kind of security does it incorporate to make sure no data is leaked and protected, especially from the admins responsible for assigning roles to users of the system. I am trying to compare it to cryptographic access control (CAC) such as ABE schemes, and therefore trying to understand the security behind it.